# How to search list of queries and combine them to a single query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a social networking app whose data model is as follows:

[image]

Here posts collection contains multiple documents with same or different tag fields, a user can follow multiple tags I already have those tags in a list I need to extract the documents where tag is equal to an element of that list and sort them according to time stamp

```
getPosts() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.hashtags.length; i++) {
        QuerySnapshot dataDoc = await Firestore.instance
            .collection("posts")
            .where("tag", isEqualTo: Constants.hashtags[i])
            .getDocuments();
    }
}
```

Here `Constants.hashtags` is list of tags that a user if following. I am able to get all documents using above code but I don't know how to merge these documents in a single and sorted way which can be further presented to user in a `List.builder` form.

Comment: you can call another `.where`

Comment: but because a user can follow multiple tags the size and tags in list are not static there can be n number of tags that a user can follow and as per my knowledge for each query we have use a different `.where`

Comment: How long the tags list is?

Comment: @meditat as it's a social networking app the number of hashtag a user can follow can range from anywhere 1-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html),

you can see the `where` has an optional parameter `whereIn`

```
Query where (
dynamic field,
{dynamic isEqualTo,
dynamic isLessThan,
dynamic isLessThanOrEqualTo,
dynamic isGreaterThan,
dynamic isGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
dynamic arrayContains,
List arrayContainsAny,
List whereIn,
bool isNull}
)
```

And you can use it Like

```
QuerySnapshot dataDoc = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("posts")
        .where("tag", whereIn: Constants.hashtags)
        .getDocuments()
```

This query snapshot contains list of all documents that has a tag field which is equals to Constants.hashtags

Comment: I'm not sure, will it work or not. But give it a try

Comment: I think this should expect `tag` as an Array, which technically should because the same post can have many tags.

Comment: `whereIn` worked as it returns a QuerySnapshot that has list of documents that i need thank you for help please edit your solution from `arrayContainsAny` to `whereIn` so i can accept it as an answer. But i am still unable to order this list as order by is giving an error `FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index`.

Comment: I found solution to `FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index` and by manual indexing in cloud fire-store thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was bit busy. I knew there is whereIn exist. But I thought arrayContainsAny will do the work. That's why I Posted that first.

Comment: This is now future proof. :)